# Setting an objectAtKey string from NSDictionary to an NSString in separate class

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have got information from a URL(JSON); I easily populate my tableView with the text from my dictionary `[aCategory objectAtKey:@"names"]`  for the cell labels. Now, based on the cell name (category), I want to display another table that will ask for the last URL in order to grab the rest of the text, based on that category.

So, i want an ID which is in `[aCategory objectAtKey:@"ID"]` to save to a string and put in the URL in the next viewController. I am currently trying to generate it using the auto-generated set method to populate the NSString *ID in the target viewcontroller; when i call 
`[newView setID: [aCategory objectAtKey:@"ID"]`.

My new view controller's NSString ID says it is not empty, but when i try to check to see if it is indeed "1" or "2" i get something like `/p2002` or something. However, in the original class, if i say `cell.detailLabelText.text = [aCategory objectAtKey:@"ID"];`, the labels correctly show "1" "2" "3".."14" etc....

SO, how can i get that ID from that key into my other viewcontroller class?

I Know it is a valid NSCFString cause i tested it both with `isClass` AND with the cell's `detailLabelText`.

Comment: Please provide some of your code once you're back at your work station.

Answer (score 0):

I need more detail to be sure about this, but a couple of notes...

NSString is what is called a class cluster, which basically means it is actually a collection of several class different classes that the underlying framework switches between...this means if you are checking it with

```
isKindOfClass:
```

you might not be getting the results you are expecting.  Check the documentation for isKindOfClass: in NSObject.

However, I am not sure if there is anything to worry about.  The reason you are seeing something like '\p2002' (Could the first letter be a u?) could just be the current underlying representation of the string.  Sometimes, when the device holds the content of the string in memory, it does not look exactly like "1" or "2".  It doesn't mean that there is a problem: it just means that, a deeper level, the way the string is being held in memory is in different form.  That is why your label might say "2" but the variable, when you check it in memory, looks different.

(I am guessing that, since you are handling JSON, the string is encoded in a form called UTF-8.)  The point is, nothing may wrong at all.

The real question is, is your new view controller loading correctly or not?  Maybe in the viewDidLoad: method of your new view controller, if you run something this line:

```
NSLog(@"%@", stringID);
```

This will print the value of stringID to the console.  If this number is the same as the number of the table cell's label in the previous view controller, everything should have been passed correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, however, despite not explicitly saying this I was sure that this was a representation of the string as i am very familiar with layers below the high level language constructs. I am positive that my view is loading correctly but even if it wasnt, it was executing my check statements within that view. I just would love an explicit answer or at least an explicit hint as to how to get a string from one class to another given it's original location, and that it is being pulled from a dictionary populated by  JSON response string.

Comment: So the problem is that you don't see how to move the string data from the firstViewController to second?

You have several options...you could set @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringID; on the second view controller and then set the value to the value from your JSON dictionary.  This will make another copy of the string in memory in the second view controller.  You could also make an initializer like -initWithStringID:(NSString *)aStringID;

As long as you copy or retain a reference to the string data, you should be able to pass the value easily.

Comment: yes, as i explained in the question i have that in my other view controller, it looks like this in the .h: NSString *ID; @propery(nonatomic, retain) NSString *ID; and I get the value from the dictionary in the PREVIOUS viewController. I am trying to use the auto-generated setID: [data] , but I am not able to correctly represent it as just "2" or "1" which is crucial since those characters need to be in the url request I am about to make.

Comment: Have you tried to actually use this string to build the URL and failed?  It sounds to me that you are doing things correctly, and if the only issue is that printing it to the console or seeing it in the debugger is showing it in a different representation than you are expecting, I would just test using the variable to build a URL string and update your question with code if there is a problem.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I should be back at the work station soon and will be able to post code if needed. I also had a realization in bed that I should have done something as simple as ask for the length of the string, which could have been helpful i would think in determining what the highest representation of that string is.